# Requiring with relative path

Tags: ruby, path, require

Programming language:

ruby

I have the following directory structure:

```
-program (dir)
--const.rb
--libs (dir)
---someClass.rb
```

I want to `include`/`require` `const.rb` from `someClass.rb`.

I tried:

(1)

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path(File.dirname.expand_path(__FILE__)))
require "../const"
```

(2)

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path(File.dirname.expand_path(__FILE__)))
require "./const"
```

(3)

```
require_relative "../const"
```

(4)

```
$:.unshift File.expand_path(File.dirname.expand_path(__FILE__)))
require_relative "../const"    (also with single quotes)
```

And they return an error:

```
`require': cannot load such file ... (LoadError)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, `require_relative '../const'` works for me.

Comment: hm, strange, I'll doublecheck it, I'll get back to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` doesn't do relative path expanding. You have to expand the path before passing to it.

```
require File.expand_path("../const", __dir__)
```

Comment: Tried it, but isn't working yet, still looking doh, but doesn't the beginning rule fix that already? => $:.unshift File.extend_path(File.dirname.expand_path(__FILE__))))

Comment: undefined "extend_path" method for file:Class (NoMethodError) fyi, ruby version: 2.0.0. Did you mean expand_path?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `expand_path`. I will fix it.